# What is a good way to implement a deep clone function for nested objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

"I am looking for a reliable approach to implement a deep clone function in JavaScript that can create a complete copy of an object, including all nested properties and arrays. While I've tried using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` for shallow cloning, it doesn't work for nested objects since it only creates a shallow copy. I want to find a robust solution that can handle cloning objects with complex nesting.

I've attempted to write a recursive function, but it's not functioning as intended. Here is my current implementation:

```js
function deepClone(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
    return obj;
  }
  
  let clone = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
  
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      clone[key] = deepClone(obj[key]);
    }
  }
  
  return clone;
}

// Usage example:
let originalObj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  address: {
    street: '123 Main St',
    city: 'New York',
    state: 'NY'
  },
  hobbies: ['reading', 'cooking', 'swimming']
};

let clonedObj = deepClone(originalObj);
```

However, any modifications made to `clonedObj` or its nested properties also reflect in the `originalObj`. Could someone suggest an effective solution to implement a deep clone function that properly handles nested objects in JavaScript? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Comment: You're wrong, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` creates a deep copy. How could `JSON.parse()` possibly keep references to nested objects intact?

Comment: There is a million of answers regarding this question.. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: And your function also seems to work for me. You must be making mistakes when testing whether changing one affects the other.

Comment: AFAICT this works fine; changes to the original or the clone don't appear to be reflected in the other.

Comment: This question makes no sense since what you want is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` but you say it's not doing what you want. Are you trying to clone an object that can't be represented by JSON? Like do your objects contain things like functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use structuredClone function
StructuredClone is new feature by which u can deep copy the objects arrays etc
Link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone
Examples

```
const obj = {name: "Mark"}
let deepclone = structuredClone(obj)
deepclone.name = "JOHN"
console.log(deepclone.name) // JOHN
console.log(obj.name) // Mark
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the code from the link in the answer. In a scenario where the link does not work, the answer becomes useless for those referring to it in the future.

Comment: Ok I will do it